# mySQL timediff wrong result

Tags: mysql

I' looking to understand why this query give me a wrong answer:

This query will format it to time, then inside of [time_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) i create a [timediff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) between 2 dates, i got only the hours.

```
 SELECT time_format(timediff('2016-11-24 08:00:00', '2016-11-24 19:40:07'), '%H:%m:%s')
```

What i need to add to get also the correct minutes ?
The result need to be 11:40:07
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Found the issue, the time_format is wrong, insted %m need to be %i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string is incorrect : `%m` is month, not minutes. The correct format string for minutes is `%i`.

Try `SELECT time_format(timediff('2016-11-24 08:00:00', '2016-11-24 19:40:07'), '%H:%i:%s')`

Answer (score -3):

sqlfiddle.com answer is 11:00:07  5.6 version of mysql

which is wrong by 40 minutes in my book.  Sounds like a reportable bug.